# Presto/Trino/Athena - Wrong subtraction of casted varchar to double

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I am using AWS Athena and trying to calculate the weight loss of each user between two samples.
My weight column is varchar, so I cast it into double and then subtract them.
I am using the following query:

```
SELECT t1.user_id, t1.sample_id, t1.weight, 
  cast(t1.weight, double) - cast(t2.weight, double) AS weight_loss
FROM my_table t1
JOIN my_table t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t1.sample_id - 1 = t2.sample_id
ORDER BY t1.user_id, t1.sample_id
```

and I get the folowing result:
[image]

Why does the calculated weight looks like this with so many floating points?

Comment: Because you asked for double data type. Perhaps you want decimal(4,1) instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Decimal](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/language/types.html#decimal) Data Type in Presto is the tool which can slove your problem.

See the following code as example:

```
SELECT t1.user_id, t1.sample_id, t1.weight, 
  cast(t1.weight, DECIMAL(10,1)) - cast(t2.weight, DECIMAL(10,1)) AS weight_loss
FROM my_table t1
JOIN my_table t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t1.sample_id - 1 = t2.sample_id
ORDER BY t1.user_id, t1.sample_id
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all as mentioned previously - you can use more precise data type i.e. `decimal`. But also I would recommend to look into [window functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/window.html), especially `lag` one because there is no need to actually perform a join (which can be quite costly if there is a lot of data and I'm not sure that Presto/Trion will be able to optimize that). Something along this lines:

```sql
select user_id, 
    sample_id,
    weight,
    decimal_weight - lag(decimal_weight) over (partition by user_id order by sample_id) AS weight_loss
from (
    SELECT user_id, 
        sample_id,
        weight,
        cast(weight as decimal(10,1)) decimal_weight
    FROM my_table)
ORDER BY user_id, sample_id;
```